# What to change in android application to make it compatible with Chromebook?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I know whatever I am trying to ask here seems very vast at first, but I will try to make it simpler and to the point.

**Problem** :

> I have developed an educational application in Unity (Android
> Platform) - now I am trying to run it in Chrome OS (v83), It works
> perfectly fine but graphics became very stretchy and blurry.

Here is the sample video of the problem that I am facing,
[Chromebook Rendering Issue](https://youtu.be/0GjyeBh_XoY)

**Specification of my Chromebook**
CPU: Intel Celeron N4000 @ 1.10 GHz
RAM: 4GB
GPU: Intel® UHD Graphics 600

Read more about processor: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/128988/intel-celeron-processor-n4000-4m-cache-up-to-2-60-ghz.html

Here are some things, which I think may cause the issue.

1. Graphics card is not good enough to render - the chances of this being the problem seems very low to me.
2. Any Unity Settings for Chromebook which I am not aware of may need to do to make it compatible with Chromebook.

Here are the solutions which I tried.

1. I tried it running on big screen android simulation and it's working just fine in all the resolution.
2. I tried looking at Chrome OS Settings to see what are various which I can try but not able to find the solution.
3. Tried reading the Android blog, Unity blog but not able to solve it.

---

> NOTE: I know the fact that Chromebook is not officially supported by
> Unity.

---

I am not sure what causes this issue, can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone who looked at the matter, I solved the problem by **enabling "Full-screen mode" in Unity player settings.**

> Why did this problem happen?

- The main problem is the resolution, The default resolution of mobile and Chrome OS is different and there is no way to know the resolution of Chrome OS and that's why I have to go forward with mobile resolution and when I maximize it - instead of changing resolution it's just stretching the current window.
- Now When I enable "Full-Screen Mode" in Player Settings - it taking default Chrome resolution and working just fine.